# 2 Linux threads simultaneously generate SIGSEGV and SIGABRT, on 2 CPUs, in same process

Tags: linux-kernel

Will these signals be also handled simultaneously on 2 CPUs, or serialized somehow? How will the resultant core file look? Usually, when I open a core, gdb says which signal terminated the process. So what would it say for this one?